# Insert parent and related child records using one SOAP API call

Tags: soap-api, relationships

Is there a way to insert a tree of records, i.e a parent record and related child records using one SOAP API call, similar to the SObject Tree feature in the REST API?

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobject_tree.htm